# If someone surrenders can I check their graveyard?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If someone surrenders because they saw something in their graveyard because of a mill effect, for example a "mill half your deck" effect sends all of the enemy win conditions to the graveyard, am I allowed to see the graveyard if I request it?

Also if I request to see the graveyard can the enemy check the graveyard before me and decide to surrender instead of showing me?

Comment: Relevant, but not a full answer: https://www.reddit.com/r/magicTCG/comments/2d0gom/rules_regarding_hiding_public_information_from/

Comment: Since you mill and you might want to protect you against not knowing the win condition, what you can always ask them to put the cards in their graveyard one by one. They aren't required to do so, following the shortcut rule, but I'd personally oblige. Although don't ask me 2 seconds between each card: it'll be one by one done quickly, for the sake of proper counting.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Once a player concedes they aren't required to show you their graveyard, as at the same time the player leaves the game so does their graveyard (rule **800.4a.**).

While rule **400.2.** means that you can look at their graveyard at any time because it's a public zone, rulings relating to **104.3a.** mean that a player can concede prior to actually showing you the graveyard after you have requested to see it.

However, as the cards that are being milled are entering a public zone it is entirely within your rights to ask to view them as they enter the graveyard, again the player can concede at this point, but you may be more likely to see what's being milled if you view the cards at the same time as the other player.

Related rules:

> **104.3a.** A player can concede the game at any time. A player who concedes leaves the game immediately. He or she loses the game.
>
> **400.2.** Public zones are zones in which all players can see the cards’ faces, except for those cards that some rule or effect specifically allow to be face down. Graveyard, battlefield, stack, exile, ante, and command are public zones. Hidden zones are zones in which not all players can be expected to see the cards’ faces. Library and hand are hidden zones, even if all the cards in one such zone happen to be revealed.
>
> **800.4a.** When a player leaves the game, all objects (see rule 109) owned by that player leave the game, any effects which give that player control of any objects or players end, and all spells and abilities controlled by that player on the stack cease to exist. Then, if there are any objects still controlled by that player, those objects are exiled. This is not a state-based action. It happens as soon as the player leaves the game. If the player who left the game had priority at the time he or she left, priority passes to the next player in turn order who’s still in the game.

Comment: Wait, so can someone concede a game rather than show me what's in their graveyard?

Comment: Yep. Concession (i.e. "take your cards and leave") trumps everything else - the rules related to it are all about how to handle it.

Comment: While concession trumps everything else, there's a different question at stake here, involving the mechanics in which the cards in a graveyard can be known. In other words, if neither of us know what's in your graveyard, and I ask to see it, is it legal for you to look through it privately first before showing it to me?

Comment: @Gendolkari Of course. Why would it be illegal?